# How to get accessor to Dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

This should be simple, but I sure can't find the answer!

Given this javascript:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here or Click to upload",
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 5
};
```

and this HTML:

```
<form action="/whatever" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
</form>
```

...Dropzone works perfectly.  BUT, I need to execute something after the upload is complete, so I added this:

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file) {
  // do something
});
```

BUT, that doesn't work.  It says "myDropzone.on isn't a function."  So clearly I need some sort of accessor to Dropzone.  I tried adding var myDropzone= to the Dropzone.options code above, and that didn't help.  I've tried doing:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone");
```

...and I get "dropzone is already attached."  I've tried renaming the ID and class of the form element, and while the errors go away, no Dropzone appears either.

So... now that my frustration level has reached 100%, here I am.  Help please? :)  Thank you.

Comment: you've probably checked that already :) but simply to eliminate potential issues : are you sure that your inclusion of the dropzone library is fine and working? 
<script src="./path/to/dropzone.js"></script> do you see it get loaded?

Comment: Since it works perfectly UNTIL I try to add the code to act on completion, I'd say it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the cause of your problem but simply trying to help :) 
(wanted to put this as reply but thought it would be more visible that way)

Here is something to try : 
In the docs, http://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation
the way they initialize options is :

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
  }
};
```

maybe you should initialize in that manner in order to be able to use the 'on' afterwards

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
  });
```

Comment: Getting closer! No more error using your suggestion, BUT, it's not acting on the on("success") event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing...

I eliminated the Form element.  I gave class="dropzone" and id="myDropzone" to the form element's containing DIV.  Now my code looks like this:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here or Click to upload",
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 5 // MB
};

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropzone", { url: "/path/whatever" } );

myDropzone.on("success", function(file) {
    alert("success");
    getUserFiles();
});
```

...and it works.